# How to escape quotes in inline styles?

Tags: html, css, xml, escaping, markup

If I have an inline stylesheet, can and I want - for some strange reason - use the same quotes that u used to encapsulate the attribute value in my html code inside the css.

Is one of these correct?

```
<div style="background: url(\"http://my-url.com/img.jpg\")"></div>


<div style="background: url(&quot;http://my-url.com/img.jpg&quot;)"></div>
```

I think the first one is correct and the second one is nonsense. Am I right or not, and why?

edit:

A co worker wrote it the second way, and the problem was that some browsers (included but not necessarily limited to internet explorer 6+7+8) requested the url INCLUDING the " signs which resultet in an 404 request.

edit 2:

okay now its really getting weird. this is the original code copy and pasted from our file.

```
<div class="cover" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://www.flimmit.com/media/search/filmcovers/105x152/ka/false/kf/false/F7780E.jpg&quot;);">
```

and this is straight from our error log:

```
13:09:45 (0.2424) [header] requ_uri        /schauspieler/Kelly+Trump/"http:/www.flimmit.com/media/search/filmcovers/105x152/ka/false/kf/false/F6TYO8.jpg"
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0001) [header] server_addr     10.48.195.172
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0001) [header] http_user_agent Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; eSobiSubscriber 2.0.4.16; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; AskTbFF/5.9.1.14019)
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0001) [error] 404-Seite wurde aufgerufen
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0386) [header] remote_ip       212.95.7.69 - AT
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0001) [header] visitor_id      4095543, -
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0001) [header] requ_url        http://www.flimmit.com/schauspieler/Kelly+Trump/"http:/www.flimmit.com/media/search/filmcovers/105x152/ka/false/kf/false/F6TYO8.jpg"
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0001) [header] http_referer    http://www.flimmit.com/schauspieler/Kelly+Trump/
Mar 18 13:09:45 (0.0000) [header] finished at 0.2816
```

this was an IE8 client. on IE6 the request uri even has `&quot;` instead of `"` in it.

So either we are all wrong or internet explorer is not respecting any standards?

Comment: There is a reason why both types of quotes are used in HTML. Is your strange reason simply asking a strange question on SO?

Comment: @Oded What a strange comment.

Comment: @Shaz - It's a strange requirement. I am wondering if the question is contrived.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: nothing, its just a css my co worker generated and we argued about it and this question was left unclear :D

Comment: from all the answers it looksl ike second way is correct, but internet explorer doesnt interpret it correctly... whos fault?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

use single quotes and I think it should be round brackets:

```
<div style="background: url('http://my-url.com/img.jpg')"></div>
```

The `&quot;` works too (tested in jsFiddle):

```
<div style="background: url(&quot;http://my-url.com/img.jpg&quot;)">test</div>
```

Comment: He says he specifically wants to use the same quotes.

Comment: sorry the brackets were my mistake. but the weird thing is that internet explorer erquests the url INCLUDING &quot;, which resulst in an 404 on our server...

Comment: @Luke Duddridge i added the raw code and error message to the answer. unfortunately i cannot test it because i have no windows system anywhere near me...

Comment: @Joe as a few have said the quot isnt always necessary, do you get the same issue without them?

Comment: no, this solves the problem. we now have single quote. its no problem to change. i just wonder why the problem happened in the first place because its all standard and conform...

Comment: @joe: just looking at the error message you added.  To me it looks like it is pre-pending some other bits, so that the url is: `/schauspieler/Kelly+Trump/"http:/www.flimmit.com/media/search/filmcovers/105x152/ka/false/kf/false/F6TYO8.jpg"`.  It looks like the url string gets built incorrectly. (also it only shows 1 forward slash after the http:, not sure if this is an error of the encoding)

Answer (score 5):

The second option is the correct one, as far as escaping is concerned:

```
<div style="background: url(&quot;https://my-url.com/img.jpg&quot;)"></div>
```

To escape double-quotes in HTML you use `&quot;`, whether in attributes or not.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/e5PPu/) (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352947/how-to-escape-quotes-in-inline-styles) SO answer).

Comment: +1 Escaping special characters as entities is always the way to go. They are expanded everywhere in HTML/XML documents and are the designated workaround for syntactically-meaningful characters. Otherwise, you'll eventually just run out of types of quotes to nest.

Comment: @Luke Duddridge Because the question is about `&quot;`, not about `{}`. The omission seems like a minor, fixable omission to me.

Comment: @zneak - Might be, might not be. I'd rather not assume.

Comment: the weird thing is that internet explorer erquests the url INCLUDING &quot;, which resulst in an 404 on our server...

Comment: @Joe - If you don't want the quotes to be passed though, don't encode them... Use single quotes to delimit the URL (or nothing at all, as they are not needed).

Answer (score 5):

First off, why?

You should be using `()` instead of '{}'

This way is best:

```
<div style="background: url('http://my-url.com/img.jpg')"></div>
```

This way is fine:

```
<div style="background: url(&quot;http://my-url.com/img.jpg&quot;)"></div>
```

This also works:

```
<div style="background: url(http://my-url.com/img.jpg)"></div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<div style="background: url(\"http://my-url.com/img.jpg\")"></div>
```

Note: Remove the space after `url`.

Comment: Why remove the space after `url`? Does it break otherwise?

Comment: sorry the brackets were my mistake. but the weird thing is that internet explorer erquests the url INCLUDING &quot;, which resulst in an 404 on our server...

Comment: @joe, hmm, I only tried it in Firefox.  You know you don't have to use quotes at all for the url. see above - I added a new sample.

Comment: @Joe, are you missing a ';' by chance.  It seems to work fine in IE7/8 for me.

Comment: @Joe, in your scenario is it possible to take the quotes out?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple double and single quotation

you can combine double and single quotation together (nested)

```
style="background-image: url( 'image.jpg' );"
```

or

```
style='background-image: url( "image.jpg" );'
```

and available to be more nested

like (if you're using template for framework (Django))

```
 style="background-image: url( ' {% static "image.jpg"   %}' ); "
```